# Will moving keep track of references?

Tags: c++, move

I was wondering if the following code is safe to use, and if not, is it possible to make it safe?

```
{
    ThreadState state = ThreadState::Running;
    auto pair = std::make_pair(std::async([&state] ()
    {
        state = ThreadState::Waiting;
    }), std::move(state));
    someVector.emplace(std::move(pair));
}
```

Will the lambda keep track of the proper reference after performing `std::move`? Will the lifetime of the state be extended? Can I improve this to create a pair of a lambda and its captured state?

Comment: Are these enums? what are you trying to do? Perhaps there is a better way?

Comment: @Nim Here is a minimal example of what I am doing. Is there a better way? https://pastebin.com/embed_js/9DKguWeK

Comment: That doesn't look right, for example, if none of the async tasks complete in the inner loop when you come to the test, then the outer loop runs again and you schedule more tasks - theoretically you can have more tasks than the batch size you require.. Below the inner loop that starts the tasks, you should wait for all of them to complete.. This guarantees that at most you will only run the number of threads you need..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will the lambda keep track of the proper reference after performing std::move?

No, the lambda will reference the moved-from `state`, which will now have an indeterminate value.

> Will the lifetime of the state be extended?

The lifetime of `state` ends when the enclosing scope ends. The lifetime of the state inside the `std::pair`, to which you move the value of `state`, will of course be determined by the lifetime of the `std::vector` you emplace/push it into.

> Can I improve this to create a pair of a lambda and its captured state?

One solution, although it uses dynamic storage, is to use a `std::unique_ptr`:

```
{
  auto state = std::make_unique<ThreadState>(ThreadState::Running);
  vec.emplace_back(
    std::async([s = state.get()] ()
    {
        *s = ThreadState::Waiting;
    }),
    std::move(state)
  );
}
```

Comment: Should I then first create a pair with an empty lambda, and swap the lambda out to capture the from the second element of the pair?

Comment: @AdamHunyadi: That will probably not work, because when you move/copy the `std::pair` into the `std::vector` (or when that vector resizes), your `ThreadState` will move as well, invalidating the reference.

Comment: @You If you only update the lambda, this should work, e.g. `vec.back().first = [state = &vec.back().second]() { }`, but of course this won't hold if the vector is resized, etc., but there are probably better design than this for what OP wants to do.

Comment: @Holt I added an example of what I am trying to do:
https://pastebin.com/embed_js/9DKguWeK